# Is there an optimized .net implementation of design patterns?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have seen .net optimized implementation of design patterns on http://www.dofactory.com. But not all patterns are available on the site. Is there a site/blog which has an .NET optimized implementations of all design patterns?

Comment: The site you mention provides implementations for most of the "Gang of Four" patterns. What other patterns do you need ? there is no "official" list of design patterns anyway...

Comment: @Thomas I am aware that they have all GoF patterns, but not all patterns have .NET optimized code, which is available only if you buy their framework

Comment: most of the 23 at http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx seem to have code. which ones are missing?

Answer (score 2):

My expectation of Design Patterns is that you don't "buy" (or otherwise acquire ready-built) implementations. Rather, as you design your classes you apply relationships that conform to the patterns. To take an extreme example, why would you "buy" a Singlton, or a Visitor pattern?

Framworks are much bigger than patterns, those it's reasonable to "buy", but there you are deliberately agreeing to delegate very major parts of your design to the framework author - and thereby save much time.

Comment: Seems strange to me as well, but maybe I misunderstood the whole site and it's used for learning? Seems much easier to just buy a decent book.

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite some time on reading [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059652773X), those 23 GoF patterns should all covered with c# examples there, hope it could help you too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can google and find their framework somewhere in the net or buy it. I was looking for a long time but never found a full imlpementation of .net optimized patterns. Instead of it I`d suggest to look for design patterns pattern by pattern in different .net open source projects.

The cons are obvious: 
you`ll be able to see implementation in the real world (and implementation of dofactory imho is far away from the real world even in their real world examples).

You`ll be able to see different implementations and the whole code structure involved in the pattern. So you`ll see how it influenced the design and what problem it solved. As patterns are good reusable design solutions it is a good way to see them in real code to use afterwards.